# Nginx point subdirectory to root

Tags: nginx, configuration, domain, directory

How can I point www.domain.com/ru/ to open the content of www.domain.com/ ?

Not a redirect.

I have tried alias and root but can't figure how to make it work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean an internal rewrite, then this should work:

```
location ^~ /ru {
    rewrite ^/ru(.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

The `^~` modifier ensures that this location takes precedence over any regex location so that your `.php` URIs are rewritten too.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: But it will redirect and I want it to only display a content of www.domain.com/ and the url will not change

Comment: Something else in your config must be causing a redirect.

Comment: Sorry, it worked!

Comment: I get `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`.